# I don't understand the line "if (index > 63)" and "bit_value = (n >> index) & 1;"

Tags: c

```c
#include "main.h"
/**
 * get_bit - returns the value of a bit at a given index
 * @n: the number
 * @index: the index of the bit we want to print
 * Return: value of the bit
 */
int get_bit(unsigned long int n, unsigned int index)
{
  int bit_value;

  if (index > 63)
    return (-1);

  bit_value = (n >> index) & 1;

  return (bit_value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your system `unsigned long` is a 64-bit value. The bit numbers (indexes) range from `0` - `63`. If you are looking for an index *greater-than* `63` that is an error and `-1` is returned. Otherwise, you shift the bits to the right (bits `0` - `index - 1` fall off the right side (are shifted off)) leaving bits `63` - `index`. ANDing with `1` simply results in `1` or `0` depending on whether the bit at `index` is `1` or `0`.

**An Example**

Let's take an example of the number `12` where bits at index `2` (the `4`'s bit) and `3` (the `8`'s bit) are both one (bits at indexes `4` - `63` are all `0`, represented by `..` below). You want to determine whether the bit at index `2` is `1` or `0` (on or off).

The binary representation of the number `12` is:

```
  ..1100
```

The `index` is `2`. So shifting the value to the right by `2` (e.g. `n >> index`) results in the number `3`, e.g.:

```
  ..0011
```

When you AND a number with `1` you are ANDing all bits with `..00000001` (showing only the final byte, all other bits are `0`). The process of ANDing `3` and `1` is, and will result in:

```
  ..0011  AND
  ..0001
  ------
  ..0001
```

So in the number `12` the bit at `index == 2` is `1`. (if you try again with `index == 1` or `index == 4` the result is `0`)

Answer (score 0):

It returns -1 for all positions greater than 64, that's the first if() check.

Then it right shifts the number by given index, and checks whether the bit is set or not.

```
shifted_number = bit >> index;
check = shifted_number & 1;
```

Comment: You are incorrect, no assignment to `n` is happening there.

Comment: You are incorrect. There are no modifications happening in `shifted_number & 1`.

Comment: You are again incorrect. `&` operator doesn't modify. There are no modifications happened in `shifted_number & 1`.